# typo in cross-site FAQ

Tags: bug, status-completed, per-site-meta

The [cross](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq)-[site](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/faq) [FAQ](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq) reads, in part:

> may be be removed.

"[M]ay be be removed"? May "be" be removed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup, that's a typo. Looks like you found it.

[image: LULZ U HAVE TYPO]

It should just be "may be removed". But then that's kind of redundant... How about:

> Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed. This includes answers that are...
>
> - commentary on the question or other answers
> - asking another, different question
> - “thanks!” or “me too!” responses
> - exact duplicates of other answers
> - not even a partial answer to the actual question
>
> If you wish to improve an existing answer, click edit. For additional guidance, see How to Answer.

Comment: Yeah, good idea. No checkmark until this is tagged status-something.

Comment: @msh it is tagged now.

Comment: @Pekka, yes, but it's tagged `status-completed`, and [it's clearly not](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: @msh it could be that the change is in the upcoming build. I think they build about daily.

Comment: @Pekka, ah, okay. Thanks. (I'd have thought the FAQ is editable online by meta.SO mods or something rather than being released as part of the software (or whatever the correct terminology is: I'm no techie).) I'll await implementation....

Comment: @msh: I was pretty sure it was done when I looked at it last night, but it's definitely completed now. I think the changes were rolled out faster to some sites than others.